# datepicker is not a function - error on homepage but works on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have been struggling with this error for a while now. Checked all my includes, compared to other pages and everything looks to be fine to me. I am honestly completely lost why this is happening.

I have a `jQuery datepicker` function on my homepage which doesn't work, it throws the error "Function not found". However, I have the exact same function on other sub-pages and no issues at all.

## css

Those are my includes from the page that works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

## Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
<script src="./index/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
```

And to compare, includes from the homepage

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
<script src="./index/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
```

I also thought that maybe I wrote something wrong so I copied the code exactly from the working page and still no luck. The only difference is that I am using Google Charts API on the homepage, could this be throwing off the datepicker? 
My datepicker function:

## JavaScript

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

And where it is used:

## HTML

```
<label for="Audit Date">Audit Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: You seem to be including jQuery twice.

Comment: I tried removing the inclusions one by one and checking it separately, no luck. And that wouldn't explain why it works on the other page

Comment: True, but it's still not a good thing to be doing

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will adjust that. Only starting with jQuery. Any suggestions what else I could check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know in which order you load the scripts, so here is the ay it worked for me:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This have worked after I added the bootstrap js at the end of the scripts. I have no idea why it wouldn't work before though. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
<script src="./index/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
<label for="Audit Date">Audit Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" >
```

Comment: check are you use another js in page